# iOS8 NavigationController back button shows where shouldn't

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios8, xcode6

In application I have root ViewController with login form who checks did user mark "auto login" checkbox and did his last login was successful. 
If yes: ViewController proceeds auto login routine and performing push to MainMenuViewController. 
If not: the user have to enter his login credentials and hit login button and after login the same segue is performed.

In the case of "manual" login everything works fine, but in the case when autologin is performed I'm getting **non functional** "back" button (without back arrow) on Navigation bar in MainMenuViewController where it shouldn't appear and after next segue back button is not shown, but it should be. Moreover after going back from next segue (with back swipe gesture) everything is back to normal.

In iOS7 this works just fine.

[image: this is non functional button which appears]
Excerpt from the code:

In MainMenuViewController I have within viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

LoginViewController 
Login method

```
...
if([self processLogin:username password:password]){
    [self goToMainMenu];
} else {
...
```

Segue method

```
-(void)goToMainMenu {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainMenu" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should solve it by programming in swift or .m file.
For example, By implementing of autologin, You should flag a login status.
that is in   goToMainMenu function, you can do it as following.

```
(void)goToMainMenu()
{
    if(flag) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainMenu" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOtherView" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer but you probably haven't read my question careful enough.